# Correctly SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL and ANSI_WARNINGS ON inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with an index that requires CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL and ANSI_WARNINGS to be ON. Here is my stored procedure to update a value in that table.

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE My_Procedure
    @Namespace VARCHAR(50),
    @Name VARCHAR(50),
    @Value VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN TRAN
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
    SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;
    UPDATE MyTable SET Value = @Value WHERE Namespace = @Namespace AND Name = @Name;
COMMIT TRAN
```

But when I `exec [My_Procedure] @Namespace='my namespace', @name='my name', @value='sp value'`

I am getting:

> UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ANSI_WARNINGS'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

If I do

```
set ansi_warnings on;
set concat_null_yields_null on;
exec [My_Procedure] @Namespace='my namespace', @name='my name', @value='sp value'
```

then it works with no errors. But I would expect that by placing these commands inside the stored procedure, it would work. What am I missing?

Comment: Instead of CREATE OR ALTER, can you try DROP, set the SET options correctly, then CREATE?

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures have special considerations for `SET` option statements, e.g.:

> Stored procedures execute with the SET settings specified at execute time except for SET ANSI_NULLS and SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER. Stored procedures specifying SET ANSI_NULLS or SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER use the setting specified at stored procedure creation time. **If used inside a stored procedure, any SET setting is ignored.**

REF: [Considerations When You Use the SET Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statements-transact-sql#considerations-when-you-use-the-set-statements)

Although `SET NOCOUNT ON/OFF` works inside stored procedures which runs counter to the above.

Comment: In the context of the whole bullet point, I think it's clear that "any SET setting is ignored" is intended only to apply to the two settings being discussed (ANSI_NULLS and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER)

Answer (score 0):

If you comment out the update and add `DBCC USEROPTIONS` to show the settings during proc execution, you'll see the options are set correctly at execution time. To wit:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE My_Procedure
    @Namespace VARCHAR(50),
    @Name VARCHAR(50),
    @Value VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN TRAN;
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
    SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;
    --UPDATE MyTable SET Value = @Value WHERE Namespace = @Namespace AND Name = @Name;
    DBCC USEROPTIONS;
COMMIT TRAN;
GO

--set required options off for illustration
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
EXEC [My_Procedure] @Namespace='my namespace', @name='my name', @value='sp value'
GO
```

Results:

```
+-------------------------+----------------+
|       Set Option        |     Value      |
+-------------------------+----------------+
| textsize                | 2147483647     |
| language                | us_english     |
| dateformat              | mdy            |
| datefirst               | 7              |
| lock_timeout            | -1             |
| quoted_identifier       | SET            |
| arithabort              | SET            |
| ansi_null_dflt_on       | SET            |
| ansi_warnings           | SET            |
| ansi_padding            | SET            |
| ansi_nulls              | SET            |
| concat_null_yields_null | SET            |
| isolation level         | read committed |
+-------------------------+----------------+
```

You will get an error at ***compile time*** if you uncomment the `UPDATE`; the `SET` statements in the proc code never execute in that case.

Modern SQL Server APIs set the ["magic 7" set options](https://www.dbdelta.com/improper-set-option-errors/) properly by default (including the "sticky" ones @AlwaysLearning mentioned). Consequently, one doesn't typically need to set them on in proc code. It seems you may be using a very outdated API or have specifically set the options improperly in code or client tool setting.